# Converting a huge .LAS into a readable 3D file

Tags: qgis, lidar, lastools, fusion, blendergis

I've got a huge (1.3GB) .LAS file that is composed of data from around the Golden Gate Bridge in San Francisco. I'm trying to get it into Blender, a 3D software, so I can look at the surroundings and make some nice renders. Does anyone know how I can easily convert a large LAS, like this, into a 3D .OBJ/.STL/.ABC?

I've tried converting it into a raster dataset, like a .TIF DEM, but I can't seem to have the file finish processing, due to its sheer size. This might have worked for my purposes, but because my dataset contains complex objects that cannot be rendered as a displacement map [top down], I can't seem to figure out how to get this dataset into Blender.

Comment: Blender supports 3d shapefiles (xyz) https://medium.com/digital-heritage/from-qgis-to-blender-visualizing-and-creating-georeferenced-3d-models-b847a8671925. (1.3GB is not necessary large size.. make sure you have lots of free ram to process las).

Comment: There is a similar question on [blender.stackexchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/141882/import-las-files), otherwitse you can use a lidar software like CloudCompare (FLOSS) to convert the las file in a DEM.